# Problemas con los indices desconocidos en un JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, api

el problema es que yo mando una consulta en ajax a un php conectado a una API de criptomonedas para poder sacar su valor.

La API necesita como parametro el nombre de la cripto y me devuelve un array asi: `array(1) { ["bitcoin"]=> array(1) { ["ars"]=> int(5040761) } }`

Yo por medio del mismo php convierto ese array en un json (adjuntare el codigo completo mas adelante), y lo devuelvo al controller que hizo la llamada.

El problema esta en el formato del json, porque como indice esta el nombre de la cripto y luego el valor, pero como los datos no son fijos, o sea el usuario selecciona una cripto por medio de un select, yo no se como se va a llamar ese indice para acceder al valor. El formato es el siguiente: `{bitcoin: {…}}bitcoin: ars: 5036931__proto__: Object__proto__: Object`
Dejo el codigo completo, pero basicamente necesito ingresar a "ars" pero para hacerlo debo saber el nombre del indice "bitcoin" en este caso.

```
function get_cripto_value(cripto){
        post_data('../../model/calculadora/calculadora2.php', cripto).then(response => {
            // En este punto recibimos la respuesta.
            console.log('cripto: '+response);
            let data = JSON.parse(response); 
            console.log(data);
            //$('#cripto_value').val(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }


<?php
require_once('../../vendor/autoload.php');
use Codenixsv\CoinGeckoApi\CoinGeckoClient;

//$cripto = $_POST['data'];

$cripto = 'bitcoin';

$client = new CoinGeckoClient();
$data = $client->ping();
$data = $client->simple()->getPrice($cripto,'ars');


$jsonstring= json_encode($data);
echo $jsonstring;
?>
```

Otro ejemplo con otra cripto seria:

```
{dai: {…}}
dai: {ars: 92.42}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podés hacer es recorrer el arreglo que decodificaste clave por clave.

Así:

```
<?php

$data = $client->simple()->getPrice($cripto,'ars');
$array = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($array as $cripto => $details) {
   $ars = $details['ars'];
   break;   
}
```

O todavía mejor:

```
<?php

$data = $client->simple()->getPrice($cripto,'ars');
$array = json_decode($data, true);

$cripto = current(array_keys($array));
$ars = $array[$cripto]['ars'];
```

Comment: esta perfecto, me re sirvio, muchisimas gracias

Comment: @AngelMagaquian me darías un upvote? :) o mejor, márcala como respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien, el objeto que intentas leer tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
   {
       "bitcoin":[
          {
             "ars":5040761
          }
       ]
    }
```

Y no conoces el nombre de ninguna de sus propiedades. En ese caso, puedes leer el objeto de este modo:

```js
var mData =
  `{
   "bitcoin":[
      {
         "ars":5040761
      }
   ]
}`;

let json = JSON.parse(mData);

Object.keys(json).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);
  json[key].forEach((item) => {
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      console.log(`\t${k} : ${v}`);
    });
  });

});
```

---

Si el objeto está siempre de la propiedad llamada `bitcoin` puedes hacer algo así:

```js
var mData =
  `{
   "bitcoin":[
      {
         "ars":5040761
      }
   ]
}`;

let json = JSON.parse(mData);

  json.bitcoin.forEach((item) => {
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      console.log(`${k} : ${v}`);
    });
  });
```

---

Y, si el objeto está siempre dentro de la propiedad `bitcoin` y se trata de leer solamente un objeto, puedes acceder directamente a la propiedad y al índice:

```js
var mData =
  `{
   "bitcoin":[
      {
         "ars":5040761
      }
   ]
}`;

let json = JSON.parse(mData);

Object.entries(json.bitcoin[0]).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  console.log(`${k} : ${v}`);
});
```

### Recomendación

Ten en cuenta que JSON existe para simplificar la programación, no para complicarla. Por lo tanto convendría usar JSON para representar estructuras de datos bien definidas que respondan a otras realidades de tu aplicación.

Pensemos por ejemplo en una tabla de base de datos donde tienes filase como esta:

```
name     value
----------------------
ars      5040761
otra     9999999
```

El JSON se diseñaría de este modo:

```
{
   "bitcoin":[
      {
         "name":"ars",
         "value":5040761
      }
   ]
}
```

Asociando cada valor a propiedades ya definidas en tu modelo de datos, eso te permitirá acceder a `ars` **usando siempre la propiedad `name`** (como harías en una instrucción SELECT de SQL por ejemplo), y al valor que tenga `ars` **usando siempre la propiedad `value`**.

Estructurar los datos así te evitará tener que recurrir a código truculento para adivinar que una  `propiedad`  ¿?  se llama `ars`  ¿? ¡No, realmente eso no es una propiedad, eso es un valor! La propiedad para encontrar a `ars` sería en este caso `name`, y **será la misma** para encontrar decenas, cientos, miles o millones de valores. Por eso decía que JSON existe para simplificar, no para complicar. Si asignas valores como propiedades simplemente estás complicando las cosas.

Comment: Hola Cedano, si, los JSON me sinfplificaron la vida pero el problema es que yo no tengo control de nombrar los indices y el indice bitcoin siempre será variable y no constnate. Por eso esa estructura y las estructuras que se, no sirven. O sea el indice bitcoin en este caso es un ejemplo, pero tambien puede ser dai o con el nombre de la cripto que elija el usuario desde el front

Comment: @AngelMagaquian en la respuesta hay varias posibilidades, en el primer bloque de código he explicado cómo leer los datos cuando no se conoce ninguna de las claves. ¿Eso no resuelve el problema?